# Why does the derivative equation of the unit semicircle equation intersect the semicircle at $x=-\frac{1}{\phi}$?

Tags: derivatives, circles, graphing-functions, golden-ratio

[image: The graphs I drew in desmos]

I was playing around in desmos and I discovered something interesting, but I am nowhere near advanced enough to tackle this.

The circle equation $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$
and its derivative (I don't know how to find the equation - if possible could you explain this as well?)

intersect at or extremely close to (as in I zoomed in as far as I could in desmos) the point where x is equal to $\frac{-1}{\phi}$ where $\phi$ is 1.6180339...

I don't know whether all 3 lines actually cross at this point, but it seems like it's too perfect to be false. Is anybody able to come up with a reason why this happens?

Comment: The derivate can be found with the chain rule. It is $$f'(x)=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ Set $f(x)=f'(x)$ to get the points of intersection (Note that only the solution in the range $(-1,1)$ is meaningful).

Comment: In fact, the solution is equal (not only close) to the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Peter's comments, the derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ can indeed be found using the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). For more background on derivatives if you'd like it, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative). The chain rule states that, for two functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, the derivative of their composition $g(h(x))$ is given by

$$\big[g(h(x))\big]'=g'(h(x))\cdot h'(x)$$

In this case, we have $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $h(x)=1-x^2$. Applying the chain rule, we have

\begin{align*}
g'(x)&=(x^{1/2})' \\
&=\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2} \\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \\
\implies g'(h(x))&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
h'(x)&=(1-x^2)' \\
&=-2x
\end{align*}

Pulling these derivatives together, we find that

\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=\big[g(h(x))\big]' \\
&=g'(h(x))\cdot h'(x) \\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}(-2x) \\
&=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{align*}

---

We can now set the function $f(x)$ equal to its derivative $f'(x)$ to see where the two intersect:

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=f'(x) \\[0.5ex]
\sqrt{1-x^2}&=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\[0.5ex]
1-x^2&=-x
\end{align*}

Rearranging this, we end up with

$$x^2-x-1=0$$

This can be solved with the quadratic formula:

\begin{align*}
x&=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4(-1)(1)}}{2} \\
&=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{align*}

Notice that this gives two solutions, whereas the two graphs you showed only intersect once. That's because the solution $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, when substituted back into $f(x)$, returns the square root of a negative number, which isn't a real solution. The solution $x=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is therefore the only real solution. Even though the golden ratio, $\phi$, is normally given as $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, note that this solution we obtained is exactly $\frac{-1}{\phi}$:

$$\frac{-1}{\phi}=\frac{-2}{1+\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{1-\sqrt{5}}=\frac{-2(1-\sqrt{5})}{1-5}=\frac{-2(1-\sqrt{5})}{-4}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

This means that all three curves you graphed do cross at the same point! There might exist some kind of intuitive explanation as to why the intersection of a circle with its derivative involves the golden ratio, but I don't know what that explanation would be, unfortunately.